# Issue in JFreeChart and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jfreechart

Can someone help me to solve this? I'm trying to create a chart using hibernate database, but I am getting an error in for loop "actual and formal arguments lists differ in length". I try to find this error online, but am not getting any solution. I decided to seek help from here. Any help would be appreciated

Here's the code for my entity class:

```
class Student1
{
    private int rno,marks1,marks2,marks3;
    private String name;

public Student1() {  }

public Student1(int rno,String name,int marks1,int marks2,int marks3)
{
    this.rno = rno;
    this.name = name;
    this.marks1 = marks1;
    this.marks2 = marks2;
    this.marks3 = marks3;

 //getter and setters
}
```

Here's the code of method charts:

```
public static void chartsStudent()
{

    DefaultCategoryDataset d1 = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    SessionFactory sfact = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = null;

    try
    {
        session = sfact.openSession();
        System.out.println("connected");
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<Student1> student1list = new ArrayList<>();
        student1list = session.createQuery("from Student1").list();
        
        for(Student1 b : student1list)
        {
            d1.setValue(b.getName(),b.getMarks1(),b.getMarks2(),b.getMarks3());
        }
        
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (session !=null)
        {
            session.close();
            System.out.println("disconnected");
        }
    }
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Student Preformance",
"Subjects","Marks",d1,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,true,false);
int width = 400;
int height = 400;
}
```

ERROR
[image: IMAGE of an ERROR]

Comment: According to the api of [DefaultCategoryDataset.setvalue()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/DefaultCategoryDataset.html), this function doesn't take String, int, int, int as parameters.

Comment: then what fuction should I use instead of set value, actually I am totally new in this.@Ynjxsjmh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62857669/issue-in-jfreechart-and-hibernate/62876278#comment111164935_62857669), the [`DefaultCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/DefaultCategoryDataset.html) mutators that add or set a value all take *three* parameters, not *four*. Each `value` is the `Number` of interest, each `rowKey` is a series and each `columnKey` is an element in the series. For example,

```
public void setValue(double value, Comparable rowKey, Comparable columnKey)
```

Based on your `Student` class, each value is the grade/mark, each series (`rowKey`) is a student's name, and each element (`columnKey`) is an assignment/test.

```
d1.setValue(b.getMarks1(), b.getName(), "Test1");
d1.setValue(b.getMarks2(), b.getName(), "Test2");
…
```

Alternatively, [`JDBCCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCCategoryDataset.html) builds a `CategoryDataset` from a SQL query in one step; the [source](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCCategoryDataset.java) is an example; more may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20JDBCCategoryDataset).

Comment: well my error has gone the chart is getting save also but it is not displaying any idea why?@trashgod

Comment: @KomalPatil: I'm not sure; verify that data is in the database and in your `List<Student1>`; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] and [screenshot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post).

Comment: Okay well its Done.Thank you so much for the help:)@trashgod

Comment: @ KomalPatil: Glad you got it sorted; if you want to elaborate, don't hesitate to edit your question or [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Comment: Hey I want to ask one more question any idea how should I validate my name ,rno, marks in java swings ?@trashgod

Comment: One approach is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13877452/230513), but see also [ask].