# How to create a stacked line chart using LineAndShapeRenderer or StackedAreaRenderer?

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart

I need to plot a **stacked line** chart using JFreeChart, but there is no predefined method for creating stacked line chart. I thought stacked area chart without color filled inside and with area outlined makes a stacked line chart, but still not know how to execute that. Also, I tried adding the values in the dataset and plot using `LineAndShapeRenderer`; that's worked but altering the dataset seems to be a costly operation.
**Note : My dataset is a category dataset and JFreeChart version 1.0.14**. Some code example can be more helpful.

This is the default dataset :

```
private static DefaultCategoryDataset createCategoryDataset(JSONArray columns, JSONArray rows, JSONArray data) {
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data.length(); j++) {
                JSONArray singleRow = data.getJSONArray(j);
                dataset.addValue(singleRow.getInt(i) , rows.getString(j), columns.getString(i));
            }
        }
        return dataset;
}
```

This is the dataset changed for stacked line chart:

```
private static DefaultCategoryDataset createCategoryDataset(JSONArray columns, JSONArray rows, JSONArray data) {
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length(); i++) {
    int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < data.length(); j++) {
                JSONArray singleRow = data.getJSONArray(j);
                dataset.addValue(sum += singleRow.getInt(i) , rows.getString(j), columns.getString(i));
            }
        }
        return dataset;
    }
```

Example parameters:

```
columns = [A,B,C]
rows = [X,Y,Z]
data = [ [0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]]
```

Comment: A typical `CategoryDataset` can have multiple series, distinguished by `columnKey`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62876278/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36671538/230513); please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach..

Comment: @trashgod I need code related to chart generation

Comment: You should review the sources cited in the tag's [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info); from a design perspective, consider `org.jfree.data.jdbc` to see how you might construct a notional `JSONCategoryDataset`.

Comment: More [tag:jfreechart] & [tag:json] related topics are addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjfreechart%5D+JSON).